# Applying var.test to every row

Tags: r, apply

Given a dataframe where colnames have sample identifiers (i.e. G1 and G2) I want to perform var.test() on each row and store some the results in a new matrix.

```
>dat
           GSM475355_G1    GSM475367_G0    GSM475370_G0   GSM475373_G1   GSM475376_G0    GSM475381_G1     GSM475383_G1     GSM475385_G1
27411     -0.89388704      0.01987934      0.38278532     0.071681020     0.373300080    -0.455644130     -0.18787241      0.65458155
35558      1.74279880      0.54368210     -0.24144077     0.307267200    -0.059902190    -0.052984238      0.13823795      0.20645618
43304      1.94601350     -0.05378771      0.02680111    -0.065221310     0.130765910    -0.090313435     -0.05756617     -0.02083588
33721     -0.29451323      0.01806831     -0.08260250     0.140903470    -0.006454945    -0.128416540      0.05237675     -0.03429079
8310      -0.79846334      1.00792070     -0.35607958     0.378528120     0.081913950     0.112047670     -0.34938622      0.25825214
46204     -3.02495300      0.07315350      0.79066850     0.091570854     0.428258900     0.565763500      0.18908596      0.88739204
21809      0.07164812      0.06946850      0.00000000    -0.005378723    -0.081427574    -0.009929657      0.15938330     -0.05795145
23277     -0.19507313      0.22079802     -0.11173201    -0.139470100    -0.059999466     0.159433840     -0.23357010     -0.02099037
```

My attempt have been to use `apply` but it doesn't seem to work, I have tried a few variation which are below for simplicity I have firstly grep the colnames with appropriate identifiers into new dataframes and named them G1 and G2. e.g.

```
G1<-dat[,grep("G1", colnames(dat))]
```

The apply attempts:

```
apply(G1, 1 ,var.test, y = G0)
apply(as.numeric(G1),as.numeric(G0),1, var.test))
```

And a few other variations with no success. I have even attempted one row e.g(`G1[1,]`) to test the function.

Comment: What "doesn't seem to work"? Please share error message (if exists) to support this vague sentence.

Comment: There are different error message depending on which attempt I use the error for the above attempt though is Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

Comment: What about just doing something like: `apply(dat, 1, function(x) var.test(x[grep("G1", colnames(dat))], x[grep("G0", colnames(dat))]) )` ?

Comment: @thelatemail I get the following error `Error in var.test.default(x[grep("G1", colnames(dat))],  : 
  not enough 'x' observations `

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @thelatemail for pointing me in the right direction! It appears for some reason you need to use `as.numeric` to get this to work.

```
dat$F.test <- apply(dat, 1, function(x)  var.test(as.numeric(x[grep("G1", colnames(dat))]), as.numeric(x[grep("G0", colnames(dat))]))[1])
```